# How to use QTimer to update a matplotlib FigureCanvas defined in another class?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, qtimer

I am using python3 with PyQt5 and matplotlib FigureCanvasQTAgg. I need to update a plot every 1 second, so I use QTimer. The timer works properly, but the plot is not updated. Here is the code:

**main.py**

```
import UI_action
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = UI_action.Connection()
    main_window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**UI_action.py**

```
import UI_layout_test
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
import mplwidget


class Connection(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Connection, self).__init__()
        self.my_widget_ui = UI_layout_test.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.my_widget_ui.setupUi(self)
        self.plot = mplwidget.Plot()
        self.my_widget_ui.pushButton_start.clicked.connect(self.__slot_start)


def __slot_start(self):
    self.plot.plot()
```

**UI_layout_test.py** (generated by Qt Designer)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(692, 602)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.widget_fig = MplWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget_fig.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 631, 481))
        self.widget_fig.setObjectName("widget_fig")
        self.pushButton_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_start.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 520, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_start.setObjectName("pushButton_start")

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.pushButton_start.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))

from mplwidget import MplWidget
```

**mplwidget.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from numpy import *


class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig = Figure(tight_layout=True)
        DPI = self.fig.get_dpi()
        self.fig.set_size_inches(850.0 / float(DPI), 720.0 / float(DPI))
        self.axis = self.fig.add_subplot(111, facecolor='white')

        self.axis.grid('on')
        self.axis.set_xlim(0, 10)
        self.axis.set_ylim(59.94, 60.06)
        self.axis.set_xlabel('Time (s)', fontsize=13)
        self.axis.set_ylabel('Frequency (Hz)', fontsize=13)

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)


class MplWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)   # Inherit from QWidget
        self.canvas = MplCanvas()                  # Create canvas object
        self.vbl = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()         # Set box for plotting
        self.vbl.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.setLayout(self.vbl)


class Plot(MplWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        MplWidget.__init__(self)
        self.i = 0
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.plot)
        self.data = [59.98, 59.98, 59.99, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60]
        print('initialization complete')

    def plot(self):
        if self.i <= 8:
            self.canvas.axis.plot(self.data[:self.i], '*-')
            self.canvas.draw()
            print(self.data[:self.i])
            self.i += 1
            self.timer.start(1000)
```

The output is:

```
initialization complete
[]
[59.98]
[59.98, 59.98]
[59.98, 59.98, 59.99]
[59.98, 59.98, 59.99, 60]
[59.98, 59.98, 59.99, 60, 60]
[59.98, 59.98, 59.99, 60, 60, 60]
[59.98, 59.98, 59.99, 60, 60, 60, 60]
[59.98, 59.98, 59.99, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60]
```

Based on the output, the function `plot` has been called and the timer did its job. However, there was no plot shown on the figure. How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: in the Plot class you have to call the MplWidget constructor.

Comment: You are using a pretty strange construct here. `Plot` subclasses `MplWidget`, but `MplWidget` instantiates `Plot` in its init function. From the code it is not clear how you use those classes, but just by looking at this construct it seems very likely to fail.

Comment: @eyllanesc if you call the MplWidget constructor in the Plot class you'll run in circles and end up with a lot of class instances, eventually breaking down the program. In any case, the question should make clear what the desired outcome is.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'm going to edit my question.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest 
that's right, I did not notice that Plot is being instantiated in MplWidget, I said it because according to what I saw was the inheritance of the Plot class of MplWidget. For me that question falls on the off-topic: **why my code is not working?**

Comment: @honeymilktea check your design, why Plot inherits from MplWidget, and create a Plot instance in MplWidget.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I removed the pushbutton for testing. `MplWidget` does not instantiates `Plot`; `Connection` does. Please see my edits.

Comment: `class Plot(MplWidget):
    def __init__(self):` ----> `class Plot(MplWidget):
    def __init__(self): MplWidget.__init__(self)`

Comment: Ok, now the very first comment by @eyllanesc applies. You never call the constructor of `MplWidget`.

Comment: Thank you @eyllanesc and @ImportanceOfBeingErnest! I am new to python and thank you for pointing this out. I still have a question: the timer is working now, but the plot itself is not updated.

Comment: We did not mention it explicitely here, but please provide a [mcve] of the issue when asking for help.

Comment: I'll come up with one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two instances of `MplWidget` in the programme.

1. The first is the `self.widget_fig = MplWidget(self.centralwidget)` from the `UI_layout_test`. This is the one which is shown in the UI, but it is not used anywhere further in the code.
2. The second is the one created through `self.plot = Plot()` inside `Connection`. This the one which is updated via the timer, but it is never actually added to the widget. Hence you do not see any of the changes applied to it.

Solution: Decide for one those and remove the other.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! Using `self.widget_fig` and removing `Plot` solved this problem.